# Extension Class for Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, extension-methods

I have the following class that incorporates two arrays: RadioButton[] and Checkbox[]. I only need one of them to be visible at a time. Since I need to do this a lot of times, I thought of making an extension method Visible to do this elegantly.

```
public class AnswerForm
    {
        public RadioButton[] rbuttons { get; set; }
        public CheckBox[] checkboxes { get; set; }    
    }

public static class FormExtension
{
    public static void Visible(this Form[] elem, bool state)
    {
        foreach (var item in elem)
            item.Visible = state;
    }
}
```

But when I try to call it

```
answerForm.rbuttons.Visible(true);
```

the extension method is not recognized. They are all in the same namespace, so it can't be an include error or something like that.

Comment: Is your `FormExtension` class `public`?

Comment: Is the extension method needs to be attached to Control rather than Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RadioButton` and `CheckBox` classes both inherit from [`System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.aspx):

```
public class AnswerForm
{
    public RadioButton[] rbuttons { get; set; }
    public CheckBox[] checkboxes { get; set; }    
}

static class FormExtension
{
    public static void Visible(this ButtonBase[] elem, bool state)
    {                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        foreach (var item in elem)
            item.Visible = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LamloumiAfif: You're welcome. One further suggestion: Start by explaining things at the beginning, not somewhere in the middle. Your answer spells out the treatment without giving a diagnosis first: What was the actual issue with the OP's code? Why do you start by mentioning the common ancestor class? ;)

Comment: I changed the argument type from Form to ButtonBase and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your extensionmethod wants a `Form[]` while the rbuttons an array is of type `RadioButton`.

```
static class FormExtension
{
    public static void Visible(this Control[] elem, bool state)
    {
        foreach (var item in elem)
            item.Visible = state;
    }
}
```

Changing it to the above example, where the type is `Control[]`, would allow the extensionmethod to be used by both `RadioButton[]` and `CheckBox[]`; and any other control, for that matter.

If you want to be more specific and disallow some controltypes to be used, change it to `ButtonBase[]`; both RadioButton and CheckBox inherit from ButtonBase.

ReSharper actually gave me a warning for the above solution because it could lead to runtimerrors: ""Co-variant array conversion from RadioButton[] to ButtonBase[] can cause run-time exception on write operation".

Below solution gets rid of that. Again, it can also be changed to Control.

```
public static void Visible<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elem, bool state) where T: ButtonBase
{
    foreach (var item in elem)
        item.Visible = state;
}
```

Last note, I have changed the array to be an IEnumerable. This extends the usage; as suggested in the comments.

Comment: You could make that extension method even more general & versatile by extending `IEnumerable<Control>` instead of `Control[]`.

Comment: That is even better indeed, @stakx. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps Resharper would not give a warning if the method didn't have the same name as an already existing property (`Visible`). I'd rename the extension method to e.g. `MakeVisible`, or `SetVisible`, or simply `Show[All]`. Using a verb instead of an adjective is a hint that the method will mutate state.

Comment: PS I find the final code example a little confusing. It's a peculiar mix between generality (`IEnumerable` instead of `[]`) and specificity  (`ButtonBase` instead of `Control`). From a didactic POV, it might make somewhat more sense to decide on either generality *or* specificity, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Actually that is not the problem. "Co-variant array conversion from RadioButton[] to ButtonBase[] can cause run-time exception on write operation". It has nothing to do with naming.

Comment: OK, thanks for adding that. I take that back then. (I'd still rename the extension method for clarity, though.) :)

Answer (score 1):

change your Visible method parameter from `Form`  to `IEnumerable<Control>` as `Checkboxes` and `Radiobuttons` are controls

```
public class AnswerForm
    {
        public RadioButton[] rbuttons { get; set; }
        public CheckBox[] checkboxes { get; set; }
    }

    public static class FormExtension
    {
        public static void Visible(this IEnumerable<Control> elem, bool state)
        {
            foreach (var item in elem)
            {
                item.Visible = state;
            }
        }
    }
```